# Huge error message from boost using time_synchronizer

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, timesynchronizer, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the modified [example code](https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28C.2B-.2B-.29-1) of the message_filters package

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>

void callback(const geometry_msgs::PointStampedConstPtr& msg,
                      const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr& imuMsg){

  static tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf2_broadcaster;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

  transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  transformStamped.header.frame_id = "ts_frame";
  transformStamped.child_frame_id = "prism_frame";
  transformStamped.transform.translation.x = msg->point.x;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.y = msg->point.y;
  transformStamped.transform.translation.z = msg->point.z;
  tf2::Quaternion q;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = imuMsg->orientation.x;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = imuMsg->orientation.y;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = imuMsg->orientation.z;
  transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = imuMsg->orientation.w;

  tf2_broadcaster.sendTransform(transformStamped);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_ts2prism");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Imu> imu_sub(nh, "/imu/data_raw", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PointStamped> point_sub(nh, "/ts_points", 1);

  message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::Imu, geometry_msgs::PointStamped> sync(imu_sub, point_sub, 10);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

the error message is not understandable:

```
warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/message_filters/subscriber.h:38,
                 from /home/mango/tut_ws/src/totalstation/src/tf_ts2prism.cpp:47:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > >&); A = boost::_bi::list9<const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>; A1 = boost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::arg<2>]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1102:50:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&&, A2&&, A3&&, A4&&, A5&&, A6&&, A7&&, A8&&, A9&&) [with A1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A9 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; R = void; F = void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > >&); L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
```

and so on... what can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297174/huge-error-message-from-boost-using-time_synchronizer/) by [rubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/36364/rubot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error is that you've switched the order of the arguments between your callback signature and your template in `message_filters::TimeSynchronizer`. In the callback, your first argument is of type `geometry_msgs::PointStampedConstPtr&`, but in the template it is of type `sensor_msgs::Imu`. If you switch one of these it should work.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/36364/rubot/) on 2018-07-12**:
this was exactly the problem! first i switched the numbers but in the end it is better to be more consistent with the arguments in the callback function. Thanks!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-13**:
Glad that fixed it!